# How to fix a text file recognized as a binary file?

Tags: text, binary

I recently moved some text files from my desktop to external hard drive.
I guess some of the files crashed, and they are recognized as binary files.

When I 'less' them, it says "may be a binary file. See it anyway?".
And when I 'file' them, they look as data files.

Has anybody fixed this problem?
Thank you.